# read network file from Oracle database using JAVA

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, readfile

I'm trying to create a function in Oracle Database which uses a JAVA class to read files from network drive and returns content of file as BLOB.

Till now, here is the progress

JAVA code - FileAPI.java

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class FileAPI
{  
  public static String readFile (String path, Blob[] outLob)
  {
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    try {       
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int i = 0;
        /* for testing just read 100 bytes */
        /* code required for reading full file */
        i = fileStream.read(buffer, 1, 100);        
        outLob[0] = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(buffer); 

        if(fileStream != null)
                fileStream.close();         

        return "success";
        }
    catch (Exception e) {       
        return e.getMessage();
        }
  }
};
```

Oracle PL/SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION readFile (p_path IN VARCHAR2, p_outlob IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'FileAPI.readFile(
        java.lang.String,
        java.sql.Blob[]) return java.lang.String';
```

PL/SQL anonymous block to test above function

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    l_temp BLOB;
    l_res VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN   
    l_res := readFile('/mnt/servername/foldername/filename.txt',l_temp);
    IF l_res = 'success'
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Success, length '||dbms_lob.getlength(l_temp));
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error info '|| l_res);
    END IF;
END;
/
```

When I run above block, then I'm not getting any error info. It's just printing "Error info ". No exception detailed are printed.

Can some suggest what's going wrong here.

Also can you please suggest to read content of full file and to append it to BLOB variable (outLob[0]) in JAVA?

JAVA details

java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Oracle DB - Oracle 11g r2 EE

Best Regards,

[updated JAVA code]

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class FileAPI
{  
  public static String readFile (String path, Blob[] outLob)
  {
    FileInputStream fileStream = null;
    Blob tmp = outLob[0];
    try {       
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(path);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int i = 0;
        /* for testing just read 100 bytes */
        /* code required for reading full file */
        i = fileStream.read(buffer, 0, 100);        
        tmp = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(buffer);
        outLob[0] = tmp;

        if(fileStream != null)
                fileStream.close();         

        return "success";
        }
    catch (Exception e) {       
        //return e.getMessage();
        return e.toString();
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: Try `e.toString()` instead of `e.getMessage()`. There are certain cases when exception message is empty.

Comment: Thanks for reply. There was some issue with array. I have fixed it. Now when I run pl/sql block, I'm getting below error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected an OUT argument at position 2 that is an instance of a user defined Java class convertible to an Oracle type got an object that could not be converted

Comment: What's the correct data mapping for Oracle datatype BLOB in JAVA? or Do I need to change my JAVA code?

Answer (score 1):

To create Blob directly from Java, you'll have to access Connection object and tell database to create a blob through it; then acquire output stream of blob object and write to it.

```java
import oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver;

import oracle.sql.BLOB;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class FileAPI
{
    public static String readFile(String path, Blob[] outLob)
    {
        try
        {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
            FileInputStream fileStream = null;
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(path);

            outLob[0] = BLOB.createTemporary(conn, true, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
            OutputStream BlobOS = outLob[0].setBinaryStream(0);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

            int len = fileStream.read(buffer, 0, 100);
            while (len > -1)
            {
                BlobOS.write(buffer, 0, len);
                len = fileStream.read(buffer, 0, 100);
            }
            BlobOS.close();
            fileStream.close();

            return "success";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to include Oracle JDBC for this to compile. `BLOB.createTemporary()` works even with Java 1.4.2 (oracle 10); starting 1.6, there's [`createBlob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob()) function in sql.Connection, which should do the same.

Also, that's a bit irrelevant to your question, but note that you can read the standard output (System.out and System.err) of Java stored procedures in `udump` logs on database server, so don't hesitate  to use `e.printStackTrace()` - it helps debugging immensely.

Comment: Thank you very much! Mean while I have tried another approach and it's working fine. I will post it shortly here

Answer (score 0):

JAVA Code

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Blob;

public class FileAPI {
    public static String readFile(String path, Blob[] outLob) {
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        Blob tmp = outLob[0];
        OutputStream ous = null;
        try {
            ous = tmp.setBinaryStream(1);
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(path);
            //System.out.println("fileStream:" + fileStream);           
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            outLob[0] = tmp;            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
            //System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fileStream != null) fileStream.close();
                if (ous != null) ous.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Oracle Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION readFile (p_path IN VARCHAR2
    , p_outlob IN OUT NOCOPY BLOB
    )
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'FileAPI.readFile(
        java.lang.String,
        java.sql.Blob[]) return java.lang.String';
```

Anonymous block for testing

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    l_temp BLOB;
    l_res VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
    -- important, this is required so that LOB pointer is passed to JAVA
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_temp,TRUE);
    l_res := readFile('/mnt/servername/foldername/filename.txt',l_temp);
    IF l_temp IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Success, length '||dbms_lob.getlength(l_temp));
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error info '|| l_res);
    END IF;
    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(l_temp);
END;
/
```

Note: required access rights should be given to Oracle user using dbms_java.grant_permission API. Server user (user running Oracle) should have read access to network share.